# What makes D a good language?

Tags: c, d

My professor recommended I do my senior capstone in D. What can it be used for? What makes it good? He compared it to C/C++ and said it's better. Why?

This post just makes D less attractive to work with:

[Why isn't D picking up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743319/why-isnt-the-d-language-picking-up)

Comment: That post is over 5 years old. A LOT has changed since then. (btw i suspect this question will be closed too, things have changed on stack overflow since then too, you might try http://forum.dlang.org )

Comment: A reasonable question to ask, but still off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Frankly, if you do not want to learn the language by yourself by simply going to place where you can download compiler or interpreter (depends what is available), then there is no point asking such questions. - Stick to the language you already use. That is my advice. D is like any other language - you either like it, or not. I would dare to say that most of the programming languages that appeared in the last decade (or two) are brilliant. Just pick one and stick to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compared to C and C++, it is safer, meaning that it cannot create the same sorts of segmentation faults by accessing uninitialized or disallowed memory.  It also wouldn't allow misunderstanding object types like C/C++ casts can do with pointers and explicit memory allocation and deallocation.  This makes the language "cleaner" feeling in some sense.

Prior to C++ standard version 2008, D also supported better delegation.  Nowadays C++ is pretty close to D delegation capabilities by providing perfect forwarding.

D delegation: http://www.docwiki.net/view.php?pageid=97

C++ perfect forwarding: https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/rvalue_references_and_perfect_forwarding.html